# How can I properly receive data with a TCP Python socket until a delimiter is found?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am receiving data from a source (Twitch IRC) that does not specify the length of the data beforehand, and it never sends a consistent amount of data. This source uses "\r\n" as its delimiter, and I would like to receive data until this delimiter is found, stop receiving to process the received data and then continue receiving. I have tried a few solutions I came up with:

```
delimiter = "\r\n"
buffer = ""

while True:
    received = socket.recv(1).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    buffer += received

    if buffer.endswith(delimiter):
        process_data(buffer)
        buffer = ""
```

This solution is not ideal as "received" is often an empty string when receiving only one byte, and this triggers an error handler in my app (because Python doesn't raise an exception when the connection goes down during a recv() call, it just returns an empty string).

```
delimiter = "\r\n"
buffer = ""

while True:
    received = socket.recv(2048).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    received_messages = received.split(delimiter)

    for i in received_messages[:-1]:
        process_data(data)
```

This is not a good solution either as split() removes the delimiter, which causes me to be unable to know whether the last element in the list is a complete message or not.

What is the best way to receive data until a delimiter is found in a Python TCP socket? The functionality I'm looking for is similar to Boost's [boost::asio::read_until()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html).

Comment: Python returns an empty string *when the peer disconnects.* It throws an exception when the conenction goes down. There is no other way you can receive an empty string. Your question is based on several misconceptions.

Comment: I wanted to learn how I could listen from a socket until the delimiter is receievd, I got my answer, I selected the answer that helped me, question was done, everyone is happy. The upvotes in the selected answer suggest this too. I don't know why would you come back to a 3 years old question just to close it because it is supposedly "caused by typos".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buffer the data and extract whole messages when the separator is found.  Example:

server.py

```py
from socket import *

class Buffer:

    def __init__(self,sock):
        self.sock = sock
        self.buffer = b''

    def get_line(self):
        while b'\r\n' not in self.buffer:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if not data: # socket closed
                return None
            self.buffer += data
        line,sep,self.buffer = self.buffer.partition(b'\r\n')
        return line.decode()

s = socket()
s.bind(('',5000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c,a = s.accept()
    with c:
        print('Connected:',a)
        b = Buffer(c)
        while True:
            line = b.get_line()
            if line is None:
                break
            print('line:',line)
    print('Disconnected:',a)
```

client.py

```py
from socket import *

s = socket()
s.connect(('localhost',5000))
s.sendall(b'a partial')
s.sendall(b' line\r\nand another')
s.sendall(b' line\r\n')
s.close()
```

Output:

```
Connected: ('127.0.0.1', 59552)
line: a partial line
line: and another line
Disconnected: ('127.0.0.1', 59552)
```

The above would work with alternate delimiters as well.  There is also a built in function to wrap a socket in a file-like wrapper where `.readline()` could be used when the delimiter is newline:

server.py (using [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile)):

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 5000))
s.listen()
while True:
    c, a = s.accept()
    with c, c.makefile('r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
        print(f'{a}: connected')
        while True:
            line = infile.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print('line:', line.rstrip())
        print(f'{a}: disconnected')
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you